# Tenant specific Homepage URLs for Azure AD multi-tenant SaaS applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, openid-connect, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant SaaS app registered in Azure.

And, each tenant has their sub-domain to access my web application (Angular/.NET Core). *Something like **somecompany.myapp.com**, **anothercompany.myapp.com***

Note that the authentication happens through MSAL (OIDC Authorization Code Flow with PKCE).

Now I need to show my app in the tenant's Office 365 portal.

But,
**How can I configure "Home page URL" for the tenant (or any other best way), so that it will redirect the user to the correct URL of the tenant when clicked on the App?**

Or, is there any way to get the Azure TenantID as a parameter for the Home page URL, so I can setup a common endpoint to redirect the user to the correct subdomain?

[image: MyApp | Branding]

Unfortunately I couldn't find any similar questions or any articles about this problem.

Comment: Since it's multi-tenant is there any need to have multiple sub-domains? If all your customers went to the same endpoint then the identity platform would determine their corresponding tenant id when they login and then in side your app I assume you have a way of verifying the allowed tenants and segregating their data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

•   Make sure the App ID URI of the application is globally unique. The App ID URI is one of the ways an application is identified in protocol messages and global uniqueness is enforced by requiring the App ID URI to have a host name that matches a verified domain of the Azure AD tenant. Thus, if the sub-domain is ‘abc.company.com’ then the valid app URI would be ‘https://abc.company.com/myapp’

•   With a multi-tenant application, the application doesn’t know up front what tenant the user is from, so you can’t send requests to a tenant’s endpoint. Instead, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants: ‘https://login.microsoftonline.com/common’

•   When the Microsoft identity platform receives a request on the /common endpoint, it signs the user in and, therefore, discovers which tenant the user is from. The /common endpoint works with all the authentication protocols supported by the Azure AD: OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0, SAML 2.0, and WS-Federation.

•   So, the path that you specify must be a subdomain path of the root domain URL. For example, if the root-domain URL is https://apps.company.com/myapp/, and the subdomain is ‘abc.company.com’, then the home page URL that you configure must start with ‘https://apps.company.com/myapp/’ as the app is registered with the Azure AD in the root domain.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-custom-home-page

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. 
1. I have a unique App ID. 
2. Since I have the tenant identifier (somecompany, anothercompany), I know the company's Azure TenantID upfront (I have a master DB where I have my registered tenants and their Azure TenantIDs) - so, it'll be https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}

Comment: One solution is to have a common landing page where the user enters their tenant identifier (e.g. somecompany) and I can redirect them to the correct URL. But I'm looking if there's any better way without this additional step. Or if I can get the tenantID to the common landing page, then I can redirect as well.

Comment: Also, you can use the URL in this form also for correct tenant authentication and app redirection : - 'https://cfbf35b2-6346-48dc-9ac2-b77e77f90933.mytenant.onmicrosoft.com' where 'cfbf35b2-6346-48dc-9ac2-b77e77f90933' is the application ID and other terms are understandable.